# I need a wireless network card for my stationary computer

Tags: wireless-networking, adapter, pci

Going to move my stationary computer and hook it up to the TV. Which is far away from the wireless router. So i'm going to need a way to go on the Internet wirelessly from my stationary computer.

I was looking at some of those.. wireless pci adapter things. But i have no idea which one would be compatible with my computer. How can i tell?

oh i have a pentium 4, Windows XP like 600 megs of ram in case any of that matters.

Edit:
Dell Dimension 2400 SEries
Service Tag: 7MLJQ31

any of that help?

Comment: Do you know what motherboard you have?

Comment: whatever came with the computer, i think there's a number in bios will that help?

Comment: D2400 has PCI, no PCIx, I like Linksys brand cards...http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124115

Answer (score 0):

You can add wireless many different ways.

If you are looking to insert a PCI card in your computer you need to know which type of PCI the card is and which type of PCI sockets are available on your motherboard.

Check out [Conventional PCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI) and [PCI Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) on wikipedia & of course check this against your computer hardware documentation (or have a look inside).

Other ways include a USB dongle and an Ethernet bridge for example. Personally I use an Ethernet bridge and I am quite happy with it. No special hardware in my computer(s), no driver to worry about, stays when I swap computers...

Answer (score 0):

According to [the specs](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/SYSTEMS/dim2400/en/sm_en/specs.htm#1105454) your system has a 32-bit **PCI** bus. As such, any PCI wireless card that has drivers for Windows XP should work, assuming your system has a free PCI slot (since 3 is not that many).